# Laravel: Join two application by one config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, configuration

My project is two Laravel applications in one folder. Why two separate applications instead of one? I have good reasons. Anyway, for example, every time I want to change the app name in the config (`config/app.php`) I go and edit the `.env` file in both directories (of the two applications) and then execute `artisan config:cache` to update the cached config.

It's not much of a task or anything, but it's a bad design I believe. So, I am looking for a way to take the values shared between these two application out to a separate file. And have these application load this file and override/apply the values inside it to the app configuration.

So, now I have a `config.php` in the root directory (which holds the other two apps in /app1 and /app2). And inside each app's `AppServiceProvider` I call the `config.php` and loop through the values and set each using `Config::set(..., ...)`.

This worked for me well, but of course changing the values loaded in the \Config package doesn't change the values that were fetched from it earlier to this point. For example `app()->environment()` returns the value set in the `config/app.php`, not the new value introduced in the global `config.php`. That's because the `App` library asked for the `env` property before I could override it!

So, what I want your help with is: you either tell me about a more smart/standard way to achieve 1 config for 2 apps setup. Or tell me where to put the code that overrides the app config with the new values from my global `config.php` (currently I put the code in `register()` in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`)

Answer (score 1):

You can share `env` settings by removing one of `.env` files and make a symlink to the other file instead of a common file. In this case if you change a file, both applications get changed values.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. But I am keeping separate `.env` files for the two application because is want to keep some configuration properties separate.

Comment: Separate configs can be done with `config/app.php` to rewrite env variables.